# Find the limit as x approaches infinity of (e^-x)lnx and (sin2x)/x

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm not sure how to evaluate the limit as $x \rightarrow \infty $ of the following:

---

$$ \bullet  \lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}\cdot \log x $$

$$\bullet\lim_{x\to\infty}  \frac{\sin(2x)}{x}$$

---

Comment: **Hint**:

$$\sin(f(x)) \leq 1$$ 

$x$ blows up as it goes to $\infty$.
Please improve your post by providing additional details regarding your work and difficulties you've encountered for further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first expression can be written as

$$\frac{\ln x}{e^x}$$

Both numerator and denominator approach $+\infty$ as $x\to +\infty$, so we can use L'Hôpital's rule.

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\ln x}{e^x}
 &= \lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\ln x}{\frac{d}{dx}e^x} \\[2 ex]
 &= \lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\frac 1x}{e^x} \\[2 ex]
 &= \lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{1}{xe^x} \\[2 ex]
 &= 0
\end{align}$$

That last equality is due to the numerator being bounded and the denominator approaching $+\infty$.

In your second expression, the absolute value of the numerator $\sin 2x$ is bounded by $1$, while the denominator approaches $+\infty$. This is like the last equality of the previous limit, therefore the limit is zero here also.

Answer (score 1):

We can also proceed without using L'Hospital's Rule.  Instead we note the inequalities

$$\log x<x-1 \tag 1$$

and for $x\ge0$

$$e^x\ge \left(1+\frac x2\right)^2 \tag 2$$

both of which can be shown by defining $e^x$ as

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
e^{-x}\log x&=\frac{\log x}{e^x}\\\\
&\le \frac{x-1}{\left(1+\frac x2\right)^2}\\\\
&\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to \infty
\end{align}$$

---

For the second limit, we have

$$\left|\frac{\sin 2x}{x}\right|\le\frac{1}{x}\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to \infty$$